# Different variations for using loops to a pattern in java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I have been trying different variations of for loops and have no clue how to make these patterns:

Pattern

```
1
121
12321
1234321
```

My code  is the following but doesn't work like the example above.

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= rows ; i++) {
    for (int j = (rows + 1 - i) ; j  > 0 ; j-- ) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }   
    System.out.print("\n");
 }
```

Comment: Try to write down in English how you would instruct someone to do it in baby-steps. For example, how to explain how line 4 would be constructed?

Comment: a.k.a. pseudocode, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: it may seems too much looping, but yet easy to understand and effective.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows=5;
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        /*print left side numbers form 1 to ...*/
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d", j);
        }


        /*Print the middle number*/
        System.out.printf("%d", i);


        /*print right numbers form ... to 1*/
        for(j=i-1;j>0;j--)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d", j);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code prints only the suffix of each line, you are missing to write `12....i` for each line.

In addition, the loop should start from `i`, not from `rows-i+1`.

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= rows ; i++) {
    //add an inner loop that prints the numbers 12..i
    for (int j = 1 ; j  < i ; j++ ) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }       
    //change where j starts from
    for (int j = i ; j  > 0 ; j-- ) { 
        System.out.print(j);
    }   
    System.out.println(""); //to avoid inconsistency between different OS
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

First note that 11*11 = 121, 111*111=12321, etcetera.

Then that 10<sup>n</sup> - 1 is a number that consists of n 9's, so (10<sup>n</sup> - 1)/9 consists of n 1's.

So we get:

```
int powerOfTen = 1;
for (int len = 0; len < 5; len++)
{
    powerOfTen = powerOfTen*10;
    int ones = (powerOfTen-1)/9;
    System.out.println(ones*ones);
}
```

Comment: If I were your professor, I would want a proof that this gives the correct pattern.

Comment: Only works with `len < 5`! If he wants to put `6` for output, you'll get wrong values.

Comment: @DavidWallace good point, looks like it doesn't work for n > 5.

Comment: Works with bigger values when `int ones` is `long ones`. You can do it with calculation, but will get error at some upper limit because of the range of datatypes. Using loops to print out each value like @amit does is probably the better solution as it works all the time

Comment: Yeah, the point is that the OP is going to Java programming class, trying to learn about nested loops.  He/she is not going to some freaky "clever mathematical tricks" class.  I feel that whether this answer is correct or not, it's entirely inappropriate for the question.

Comment: You can use `powerOfTen *= 10`, and you can also put that into the `for` loop. In fact, you never actually use `len` so that can go. The code could do with a little tidying.

Answer (score 3):

Code explains everything!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String front = "";
    String back = "";
    int rows = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        System.out.println(front+i+back);
        front += i;
        back = i + back;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more elegant to just iterate over `i`, instead of introducing an extra variable that's not actually used, other than as the index of iteration?

Comment: @DavidWallace Made the changes as u suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
int n=0;
for(int m =0; m<=5; m++){
  for(n= 1;n<=m;n++){
        System.out.print(n);
    }

    for(int u=n;u>=1;u--){

      System.out.print(u);
    }
    System.out.print("");
}
```